# Update value of associative array with corresponding value from second array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays in php:

*Array1:*

```
array(
    "0" => array(
        "book_title" => "Book Title 1",
        "date_added_wp" => "2022-01-31",
        "author" => "xxx",
        "book_review" => "book review 1",
        "read" => "0",
        "selected" => "0"
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "book_title" => "Book Title 2",
        "date_added_wp" => "2022-01-31",
        "author" => "xxx",
        "book_review" => "book review 2",
        "read" => "0",
        "selected" => "0"
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "book_title" => "Book Title 3",
        "date_added_wp" => "2022-01-31",
        "author" => "xxx",
        "book_review" => "book review 3",
        "read" => "0",
        "selected" => "0"
    )
);
```

*Array2:*

```
array(
    "0" => array(
        "book_title" => "Book Title 1",
        "read" => "0",
        "selected" => "1"
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "book_title" => "Book Title 2",
        "read" => "1",
        "selected" => "1"
    )
);
```

I need to get the values of "read" and "selected" from the second array based on matching "book_title" field as follows:

**Result:**

```
 array(
    "0" => array(
        "book_title" => "Book Title 1",
        "date_added" => "2022-01-31",
        "author" => "xxx",
        "book_review" => "review text 1",
        "read" => "0",
        "selected" => "1"
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "book_title" => "Book Title 2",
        "date_added" => "2022-01-31",
        "author" => "xxx",
        "book_review" => "review text 2",
        "read" => "1",
        "selected" => "1"
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "book_title" => "Book Title 3",
        "date_added" => "2022-01-31",
        "author" => "xxx",
        "book_review" => "review text 3",
        "read" => "0",
        "selected" => "0"
    )
);
```

It is that I can remove the "read" and "selected" fields from *Array1* but, it will have to be added back to the **Result** as a new field.
I did try `array_merge()` as below:

```
$result = [];
        foreach (array_merge($Array1, $Array2) as $row) {
            $result[$row->book_title] = ($result[$row->book_title] ?? []) + $row;
        }
```

And, a few other iterations too, just can't seem to work this out. Any help is welcome.

Comment: `array_merge` is absolutely not suitable for this purpose. It would just take the complete items of the second array, and append them as new items into your first one.

Comment: You need to loop over one of those arrays - and then _find_ the item with a corresponding book_title in the other one. If you find one, then append the data.

Comment: You could also transfer your first array first, so that it uses the book title (which are unique, I assume?) as array key, instead of a numeric one. Then you can loop over your second array, and simply check using `isset`, whether the corresponding element in the first array exists. (And if you want numeric indices in the final result again, you can apply `array_values` after.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
 foreach($Array2 as $k=>$v){
     if($Array2[$k]['book_title'] == $Array1[$k]['book_title']){
         $Array1[$k]['read'] = $Array2[$k]['read'];
         $Array1[$k]['selected'] = $Array2[$k]['selected'];
     }
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($Array1);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @isha, this code works, but some how seems to miss the last row, any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @Maklas, In this code, Array2 finds its matching value[book_title] in Array1, If it finds the same, it will edit Array1 [read] and [selected] values as present in Array2. And when you print Array1, it will return complete Array1 including last row which is not present in Array2 as your desired result. In short, it will edit only that rows which are present in both the arrays.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Isha. And, first of all thank you for the answer. I changed the data retrieval query, to reflect the read and selected properties in the same array. I didn't want to iterate through the whole array, which will take too much time with a lot of data.